# Two terminology question about relations

Tags: elementary-set-theory, terminology, relations

Is there a name for constructing a set from a relation (or, more generally speaking, from a set of pairs that are tuples)? For example, let $R = \{(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3)\}$; if you collect all the second elements in the tuples (pairs) you get $A = \{1, 2, 3\}$.

Is there a name for the subset of a relation for which the first element in each list is a certain $x$? This means that there is some sort of filter operation $f(x, R)$ that gives you $R'$, where $R'$ is the subset of $R$ with all the pairs in $R'$ having $x$ as its first element.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The set $A$ in your first example is the *range* of $R$, commonly written $\operatorname{ran}R$ or $\operatorname{rng}R$. I’m not aware of a standard notation for what you want in your second example. If $R$ is a relation on $D$, that set is $R\cap\big(\{x\}\times D\big)$. If I were going to need it at all often in something, I’d define some reasonably convenient *ad hoc* shorthand notation for it, probably $R_x$.

If you simply want the second components of all of the pairs in $R$ having $x$ as first component, that can be written $R[\{x\}]$. More generally, if $A\subseteq D$, $$R[A]=\left\{y\in D:\exists x\in A\big(\langle x,y\rangle\in R\big)\right\}\;.$$

Comment: Typo: In the definition of $R[A]$, "$\exists x \in D$" should be "$\exists x \in A$".

Comment: @BrianO: And it should have been $y\in D$ rather than $y\in A$; thanks!

Comment: @BrianM.Scott - Hi Brian, quick question on the terminology used when talking about relations: Given a relation $R$, when we write $xRy$ could we read this as “$R$ relates $x$ to $y$“? I understand the most common way of reading $xRy$ is “$x$ is $R$-related to $y$”, but regardless I would love your input. Thank you for your time as always.

Comment: @TaylorRendon: You could. However, it puts the focus on $R$, and I think that in most contexts you want the focus to be on $x$ and $y$. When reading an expression involving $x\,R\,y$ aloud to a class, I think that I usually said $x$ *is* $R$ *to* $y$ or even simply $x\,R\,y$ (*eks ar wye*).